# Automatically pass data variable to view in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

I have a controller class that extends CI_Controller:

```
class Admin_Controller extends CI_Controller {      
    var $data;

    function __construct () {
        parent::__construct ();

        $this->load->model ('loginm');

        if(!$this->loginm->is_login_admin ())
            redirect (base_url ('admin_login'));

        $this->data['page_title'] = 'Default page title';
        $this->data['page_url'] = $this->uri->segment (2);
    }
}
```

In the others class that extend this one i have to pass $this->data variable to each view that I call in the methods. Is there some hack or config that allow me to automatically pass this->data variable when I call $this->load->view('viewname', $this->data) without passing it each time? It's not a big problem passing each time i call this->load->view, but if I can skip this it would be better.

Comment: ot be fair, this is where CI sucks. with laravel, these basic things become so easy....

Comment: @itachi, now, let's not start a framewar.

Comment: @MaximKumpan i agree but in this case, it can be advice that since CI has uncertain future ahead, it is time to move to a new framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function in your Admin_Controller to wrap the `$this->load->view()` method

```
public function loadView($viewname) {
   $this->load->view($viewname, $this->data);
}
```

Then just call `$this->loadView('viewname')`;

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the `CI_Loader` [core class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) and add a wrapper for your view function and move the common data generation to a helper function.

Personally, I always create `MY_Loader::site_view($view, $data)` and `MY_Loader::admin_view($view, $data)` function for displaying a header and footer, separate for the site and admin page. Optionally, these also display common data generated by a helper.